# chrome-linux/chrome: undefined symbol: wl_proxy_marshal_constructor

Tags: puppeteer

Trying to run puppeteer headless (v5.4.1) on amazon linux 2. I've run the `ldd chrome | grep not` and didn't get any output so I assume I have all the dependencies. I haven't been able to find anything specific about this error with a google search so any guidance would be appreciated.

My launch config looks like this:

```
    const browserConfig = {
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      headless: this.config.headless,
      devtools: !this.config.headless,
      args: [
        '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
        '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
        '--enable-logging',
        '--vmodule=/webrtc/=2,/libjingle/=2,*=-2',
        '--no-sandbox',
        `--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=${path.resolve(__dirname, 'audio1.wav')}`
      ]
    };
```